# Run Length Smoothing Algorithm(RLSA) in MATLAB

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing

I have following RLSA code in matlab.The jist of this algorithm is that it tries to connect area with specified spacing(threshold) for example in identifying text areas(As text has mostly fixed specific spacing most of the times on images) it tries to join them so that when some morphological operations are performed they do well in identifying those areas.

```
1.function result=RLSA(image,hor_thresh)
2.        zeros_count=0;
3.        one_flag=0;
4.        hor_image=image;
5.        [m,n]=size(image);
6.        for i=1:m
7.            for j=1:n
8.                if(image(i,j)==1)
9.                    if(one_flag==1)
10.                        if(zeros_count<=hor_thresh)
11.                            hor_image(i,j-zeros_count:j-1)=1;
12.                        else
13.                           one_flag=0;
14.                        end
15.                        zeros_count=0;
16.                   end
17.                    one_flag=1;
18.                else 
19.                    if(one_flag==1)
20.                        zeros_count=zeros_count+1;
21.                    end
22.                end
23.            end
24.        end
25.        result= hor_image;
26.        end
```

The above MATLAB code was taken from the following sites

[answers.opencv.org](http://answers.opencv.org/question/27866/implementation-run-length-smoothing-algorithm-in-c/)

[Attempt to implementation Running Length Smoothing Algorithm in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21607017/attempt-to-implementation-running-length-smoothing-algorithm-in-c)

More detailed description is here

[Working of RLSA](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/318198)

The above code does not work for all threshold values.For example on putting threshold value=20 I got following error

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.


Error in RLSA (line 11)
                    hor_image(i,j-zeros_count:j-1)=1;
```

Can somebody explain me the working of algorithm on images with text and as to why this code doesn't work for all of the threshold values?
Moreover,Do I need to take two pass(as described in the links given) of this code one for horizontal and one for vertical and logically and them or the mentioned code has already taken care of it?

Comment: The debugger will probably tell you if you set a breakpoint at line 11 and watch the values of `j` and `zeros_count`.

Answer (score 1):

Well it all depends on the image you pass in along with the Hor_Thresh.  I would guess that the problem is that j-zeros_count can be negative.  That would be possible if one column of an image has a 1, but within 20 pixels of another column, that has a 1.  Then the range that is being set to 1 will span 2 columns.

I don't really know what the algorithm is trying to do, but it appears to be dealing with binary images (but not explicitly).  It is setting spans of zeros (book-ended by ones) that count < Hor_Threshold, to all be 1.  So if there is "short" runs of zeros, they will be set to 1.

Guessing from the name of the parameter, I would expect to see some reset code between the 2 for loops.  The Hor_Threshold implies Horizontal threshold, i.e. it gets reset each and every column.
So between the i and j loop, I think you need to reset your 2 flags:
    zeros_count = 0;
    one_flag = 0;

It has been a long time since I have used Matlab, I have been using a similar language, Igor Pro for a while, so I tested things out in Igor.  This is the translated function:

```
Function/Wave RLSA(image,hor_thresh)
    Wave Image
    Variable Hor_Thresh

    Variable zeros_count = 0;
    Variable one_flag = 0;
    Duplicate/FREE Image, hor_image
    Variable m = DimSize(Image,0)
    Variable n = DimSize(Image,1)
    Variable i, J
    for (i = 0;i < m;i += 1)
        for (j = 0;j < n;j += 1)
            if (image[i][j] == 1)
                if (one_flag == 1)
                    if (zeros_count <= hor_thresh)
                        hor_image[i][j-zeros_count,j-1] = 1;
                    else
                        one_flag = 0;
                    endif
                    zeros_count = 0;
                endif 
                one_flag = 1;
            else 
                if (one_flag == 1)
                    zeros_count += 1;
                endif
            endif
        endfor
    endfor
    return hor_image;
end //RLSA
```

Igor, like C++ is zero based indexing.
So I could get the same error with an image that I created:

```
Make/N=(24,24) Image
Image = 0
image[0][22] = 1
image[1][2] = 1
RLSA(image,20)
```

Throws the same error as you have.
So I have 2 ones in the image, that are separated by 3 zeros (< second argument), but are in different columns.